# Put in a column this phrases

Tags: python, parsing, urllib2

Using urllib2, I tried to save a lyrics from an HTML file. Well.. 
This is the code:

```
generate_url = 'http://azlyrics.com/lyrics/' + artist_split + '/' + title_split + '.html'

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(generate_url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            print "Lyrics doesn't exist. Please try again."
            time.sleep(0.75)
            UMM.lyrics_from_track()

        read_lyrics = response.read()

        #Parsing HTML file containing lyrics
        parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(read_lyrics), parser)
        lyrics = tree.xpath("//div[@style='margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;']/text()")

        print ''
        print  '\033[32m-----------------------------------------\033[0m' 

        for words in lyrics:
            print str(words).strip()

        print  '\033[32m-----------------------------------------\033[0m'

        print ''
        save = raw_input("Do you want to save this lyrics in a txt file in current working directory? [Y/N] ")
        if save == 'y' or save == 'Y':
            f = open(artist + '_' + title + '.txt', 'w')
            f.write(str(lyrics).strip())
            f.close()
            print 'Return to main menu.'
            time.sleep(0.75)
            UMM.read_information()
        elif save == 'n' or save == 'N':
            print 'Return to main menu.'
            time.sleep(0.75)
            os.system('clear')
            UMM.read_information()
        else:
            print 'Incorrect choice.'
            time.sleep(0.75)
            UMM.lyrics_from_track()
```

The output if you want to save lyrics in a txt file is this:

> ['\r\n', '\r\nSo close no matter how far', "\nCouldn't be much more
>   from the heart", '\nForever trusting who we are', '\nAnd nothing else
>   matters', '\n', '\nNever opened myself this way', '\nLife is ours, we
>   live it our way', "\nAll these words I don't just say", '\nAnd nothing
>   else matters', '\n', '\nTrust I seek and I find in you', '\nEvery day
>   for us something new', '\nOpen mind for a different view', '\nAnd
>   nothing else matters', '\n', '\nNever cared for what they do',
>   '\nNever cared for what they know', '\nBut I know', '\n', '\nSo close
>   no matter how far', "\nCouldn't be much more from the heart",
>   '\nForever trusting who we are', '\nAnd nothing else matters', '\n',
>   '\nNever cared for what they do', '\nNever cared for what they know',
>   '\nBut I know', '\n', '\nNever opened myself this way', '\nLife is
>   ours, we live it our way', "\nAll these words I don't just say",
>   '\nAnd nothing else matters', '\n', '\nTrust I seek and I find in
>   you', '\nEvery day for us something new', '\nOpen mind for a different
>   view', '\nAnd nothing else matters', '\n', '\nNever cared for what
>   they say', '\nNever cared for games they play', '\nNever cared for
>   what they do', '\nNever cared for what they know', '\nAnd I know',
>   '\n', '\nSo close no matter how far', "\nCouldn't be much more from
>   the heart", '\nForever trusting who we are', '\nNo nothing else
>   matters\r\n', '\r\n']

How do I to put in columns the verses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to replace:

```
f.write(str(lyrics).strip())
```

with

```
f.write("\n".join(lyrics).strip())
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if you are happy with it.

Comment: @Black_Ram remember that the best way to say thanks in SO is upvoting/accepting ;)